# What is the following method of declaring a function called in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I've seen classes written in this format:

```
class A;
class B;
class C;


class A {
    friend class B;
private:
    int var1;
    int var2;
public:
    A() {}
    A(int x, int y) {
        var1 = x;
        var2 = y;
    }
};

class C {
private:
    int var1;
    int var2;
public:
    C(int var1, int var2) {
        this->var1 = var1;
        this->var2 = var2;
    }
};

class B : public C {
    explicit B(const A& x) : C(x.var1, x.var2) {};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    A a(5, 4);
    B* b = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm perplexed at the function written:

```
explicit B(const A& x) : C(x.var1, x.var2) {};
```

Now there are two things that I know about this is that it can be used to call a reinterpret cast of an instance of class A as an instance of class C and that the colon sort of maps the left-hand method with the right-hand method. By mapping, I mean mapping the explicit B(cont A& x) to A(x.var1, x.var2).

I wanted to know, what is it called when you map a function on another like that? and also, will a reinterpret cast here still make a pointer point at the memory location as a pointer of the intended class or will it just create a new instance of A using the said variables?

Thanks.

Comment: a bit more context is required, as posted this code should not compile. This is not "mapping one function to another" but to be sure what it actually is you have to show something that is valid code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That's true. I overlooked that because I was mainly perplexed by the ':' operator. Code updated.

Comment: is it maybe `class B : A ...` ? otherwise this code still makes no sense

Comment: There seems to be some errors: E.g. in 2nd constructor of `A`: `this.var1` is wrong -> should be `this->var1`. Furthermore, why the assignment? Why not simply `A(int var1, int var2): var1(var1), var2(var2) { }`? The latter would be the "idiomatic" construction (incl. the confusing mix-up of arguments with member variables of same name which is (Suprise!) correct and correctly compiled). And, btw. in a constructor, the `:` isn't a mapping. It starts the initialization of super classes and member variables.

Comment: More about this: [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the comments. I haven't had a second to sleep so apologies for my poor code as I'm trying to reinterpret proprietary code. I've posted a proper example now. @Scheff

Comment: What's wrong with `explicit B(const A& x) : C(x.var1, x.var2) {}`? It constructs `B`, initializes the super class `C` with the members taken from argument `x` of type `A`. The colon `:` is just what starts the initializers in a constructor. I cannot see any "reinterprete cast".

Comment: It can be used to do an explicit conversion from A to B. (Every constructor with single argument of different type can do this.) Without `explicit` it can do it even implicitly but this is not what the author might want. Hence `explicit` can be denoted.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you. So to call that method should I run:
`B b(A*)`? and it will return an instance of B that has had the constructor `C(int var1, int var2)` called?

Comment: @Scheff How would I call the method to make an explicit conversion?

Comment: No. You have to call the constructor of B with an instance of A, e.g. `B b(A(1, 2));`

Comment: I made a small sample concerning the `explicit`: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54e172cea757bda). `class A` can be converted implicitly from `int`, in opposition to `class B` which requires explicit conversion.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you so much. Rusty on my C++ and I'm interning, so I'm working with code that's really testing my base knowledge. The sample helped me understand things clearly. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a constructor, not a method. It doesn't map anything to anything. It defines a constructor for class `B`. That constructor invokes a constructor for the base class of type `C`, passing it the appropriate arguments.

I think you should stop using `reinterpret_cast`. From your question it seems you are using it completely inappropriately, which can be dangerous and hide bugs. The purpose of `reinterpret_cast` is to override the safety of the type system, and since you don't understand C++ well yet you should be working **with** the type system, not trying to defeat it.

> will a reinterpret cast here still make a pointer point at the memory location as a pointer of the intended class or will it just create a new instance of A using the said variables?

All your `reinterpret_cast` does is lie to the compiler, it doesn't create any new instance of anything.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't using a reinterpret_cast in my own code. There was that somewhere in the original author's code and I assumed it had to do with the explicit conversion.